# PyInstaller makes my 4kb python program 163MB. Is this normal?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pyqt4, pyinstaller

There are dozens of questions on here asking how to decrease the size of Py2EXE and PyInstaller windows binaries (complaining about executables 10MB in size), but my issue is two orders of magnitude greater, as **my PyInstaller binary is over 160MB!** I'm importing TK, PyQT4, scipy, numpy, and a few other doozies. I understand each of these binary packages is huge, so my question is if this sheer size is to be expected. Do I just have to suck it up and deal with it, or is there something I can do to shave off 100+ MB?

My imports are:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph
import time
import pyqtgraph.exporters
import webbrowser
import pyaudio
import time
import threading
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
import scipy.io.wavfile
```

I'm building my primary script (go.py) with PyInstaller using:

```sh
pyinstaller.exe -y -F --distpath="./build" -p "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4" go.py
```

**Is 160+ MB expected?** Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I would say with PyQT, numpy and scipy, that is to be expected, yes.

Comment: _TK, PyQT4, scipy, numpy, and a few other doozies_ have you tried simply checking size of pre-built Windows version of these packages, summing it up and then comparing them?

Comment: yes because its packing pyqt along with everything else.

Comment: The whole point of programs like pyinstaller is that they include **all** the dependencies required to run your program in one executable. The alternative is to put the burden on the user, and make *them* install all the dependencies separately, whilst your package just includes the python files.