# Deploy a NumPy script as a small binary, how?

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

I have a NumPy script that I'd like to "compile" into a small standalone program so I can deploy it easily on AWS Lambda. I've tried PyInstaller but the end program is huge (like 500 MB) despite my script only using a tiny part of NumPy. Is there some sort of NumPy to C transpiler out there or something? I'm looking into manually rewriting my NumPy code in TensorFlow and then using XLA AOT, but it's pretty cumbersome.

For example, saving the following as `main.py`

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
y = x * 2

print(y)
```

and then calling `pyinstaller main.py` results in a `dist` directory of 578,5 MB.

Comment: [Here I googled "Numpy to C transpiler" for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=numpy+to+c+transpiler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @saintsfan342000: And the results are pretty useless

Comment: 500mb is awfully large - [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817817/pyinstaller-makes-my-4kb-python-program-163mb-is-this-normal) seems to be using far more modules, yet comes to only 163mb. Are you sure something else isn't bloating it?

Comment: @Eric I dunno.  That Reddit thread points to [this project](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/py14) which is pretty interesting.

Comment: I'll admit I've only given a cursory glance, but that doesn't look like it'd work with a C extension module like numpy that relies on the CPython api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nuitka.net/ works great for compiling a NumPy script to a portable distribution. Simply:

```
pip install nuitka
nuitka --standalone main.py
```